# Disable message response when message was sent to all users of a role

Tags: 7, users, notifications, privatemsg

Is it possible to disable the functionality to reply to a message, when this message was sent to all the users of a role?
I know it is possible to disable the functionality to reply to messages, but I only need it to be disabled when the message was sent to a particular role, all users of a role.

Comment: Please edit your question to elaborate on those messages: do you mean messages created via the privatemsg module (as one of your tags seem to indicate)? Or could it be just any message, no matter what technique was used to produce such message? Also: are you talking about eMail messages, or any other type of messages (eg if using the "message stack"). Sorry for all those questions about your questions, but there are way too much possibilities to translate (without i18n ...) your question ...